# Firebase Retrieving Data by multiple where condition

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've trouble in retrieving data from firebase database.
Here is my table structure.

[image: My Database Structure]

Here is my code to retrieve data.

```
firebase.database().ref('messages/')
.orderByKey()
.startAt(C5)
.endAt(C4)
.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
  console.log(snapshot.val()); 
});
```

Comment: You're not using this correctly, your concept is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the nodes in your screenshot has a key in the range `C5`...`C4`, which is actually an empty range. The keys in our screenshot are `1` and `2`.

If you're trying to find all messages from users in the range `"C4"`...`"C5"`, then you can do so by:

```
firebase.database().ref('messages/')
.orderByChild("from_id")
.startAt("C4")
.endAt("C5")
.on('value', function(snapshot) { 
  snapshot.forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message.val());
  });
});
```